# Description list with image beside each description, delineated by description titles

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

Can someone explain why the following snippet of code doesn't place the image for service 1 to the left-side of div which contains dt and dd?

I was expecting the `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` to cause the image to sit inline with the div.
I also tried adding `display: inline;` to `#service_1:before` and `#service_1`. But this didn't have an affect.

When I removed the div and added `<dt id="service_1">` (with `display: inline;` still set) the text moved inline, but  content no longer rendered below , and I couldn't find a way to raise the  inline with the top of the image.

CSS:

```
#service_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#service_1:before {
  content: url('https://www.minden-luebbecke.de/media/custom/1891_130_1_m.JPG')
}
```

HTML:

```
<dl id="service_list">
    <div id="service_1">
        <dt style="">Service 1</dt>
        <dd style="">service one features</dd>
    </div>
    <div id="service_2">
        <dt style="">Service 2</dt>
        <dd style="">includes service one features</dd>
        <dd style="">and a few extra features</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

display: flex; - https://jsfiddle.net/37ae6p0v/1/
display: flex + inline; - https://jsfiddle.net/58sjd0zg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the image is a child of the first service div you need to flex that div instead of the `<dl>`.  Also you need to contain the `<dt>` & `<dd>` of that div.

In my example I changed to class selectors instead of using id to limit the specificity.  I also think there is probably more semantic html to use instead of a dl with divs, maybe look into using a list with list items instead.

```
<dl class="service-list">
    <div class="service-1">
        <div>
            <dt>Service 1</dt>
            <dd>service one features</dd>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-2">
        <dt>Service 2</dt>
        <dd>includes service one features</dd>
        <dd>and a few extra features</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

```
// Uncomment if you want the services to be inline
// .service-list {
//   display: flex;
//   flex-wrap: wrap;
// }

.service-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service-1:before {
  content: url('https://www.minden-luebbecke.de/media/custom/1891_130_1_m.JPG');
}
```

Comment: That's much closer to my intended layout. I've create a jsfiddle with a couple of tweaks. https://jsfiddle.net/t5r16pa0/0/ But can you explain why nested div's are required? I was using :before to place the image before the div content, because I expected the nested dt/dd would then populate next to it similar to a float, or the table example I provided to David below

Comment: Sorry for the delay. `::before` creates a pseudo-element first child of the selected element. Adding `::before` and flex to `service-1` means `service-1` has 3 children and they are flex items, so they are positioned on the main-axis (inline with each other). By wrapping the `dt` and `dd` can position themselves as they normally would without the flex container (`service-1`) removing their default behavior.

References:
[::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)
[flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question, but by my interpretation I edited your fiddle you can have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wmkc8296/). I replaced your child `div` tags and replaced them with sub-list `dl` tags (I think that is more semantically correct. Also, and I think this is the important bit, I added `align-items: flex-end;` to your `#services-list` selector.

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Here's an expansion of the question which hopefully will provide some clarity. https://jsfiddle.net/f4smg3v1/. A mockup using tables to give an idea of the intended layout of each dt/dd set is: https://jsfiddle.net/w2atrfzd/